# Override composer package type upon installation

Tags: composer-php, kirby

Is there a way to override a composer package type upon installation? I want to install a composer package which uses a custom type. This type leads into a custom installation path.

What I try to achieve is to ignore the custom installation path and put all the sources under vendor. Is this possible?

The custom type is handled by a composer plugin: https://packagist.org/packages/getkirby/composer-installer

Comment: @yivi The package isn't published yet but the custom type is `kirby-plugin` which copies the sources to  specific folder outside `vendor`. I want to reuse some parts in another context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "override" a package type without actually forking the package.

And most of the time, wouldn't actually do anything, since the [type is only used by custom installer logic](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type). So unless one is actually using a composer plugin with installer logic... the `type` field does not accomplish anything.

Since you now mention that you are attempting to do this for a Kirby Plugin...

Kirby uses its own custom installer: [composer-installer](https://github.com/getkirby/composer-installer).

In the docs is mentioned how to [choose a different installation directory for plugins](https://github.com/getkirby/composer-installer#custom-installation-path-1). Following these instructions, to actually install your plugins in `vendor` it would in theory as simple as doing:

```json
{
  "require": {
    "getkirby/cms": "^3.0",
    "superwoman/superplugin": "^1.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "kirby-plugin-path": "vendor" // change this to your custom path
  }
}
```

Sadly, it does not seem you can do this just for one specific plugin, as you would be able to do if Kirby just used [composer/installers](https://github.com/composer/installers#custom-install-paths).